# Can GeoPandas accept lists as property values?

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, geo

Properties in GeoJSON features can be lists (or "arrays" in Javascript). For example, the following GeoJSON feature is formatted correctly, and includes a `values` property that is a list:

```
{
    type: "Feature",
    geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [149.043, -35.227],
    },
    properties: {
        district: "Belconnen",
        values: [0.62, 0.68, 0.74]
    }
}
```

However, GeoPandas seems unable to handle properties that are lists. A value error is called if I try to write a list directly into a GeoDataFrame:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

# define geodata
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
gdf["district"] = ["Belconnen", "Gungahlin", "Molonglo"]
gdf["geometry"] = gpd.points_from_xy(
    [149.042, 149.131, 149.047],
    [-35.227, -35.179, -35.295]
)

# attempt to write a list into GeoDataFrame cell
gdf.at["Belconnen", "values"] = [0.62, 0.68, 0.74]
```

This yields the following error:

`ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

I tried an alternative way around this problem: I converted a Pandas Dataframe, which *does* allow columns of lists, into a GeoDataFrame and then added the `geometry` column later.

```py
import pandas as pd, geopandas as gpd

# define dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["district"] = ["Belconnen", "Gungahlin", "Molonglo"]
df["values"] = [
    [0.62, 0.68, 0.74],
    [0.55, 0.61, 0.67],
    [0.59, 0.66, 0.73]
]

# convert to geodataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
gdf["geometry"] = gpd.points_from_xy(
    [149.042, 149.131, 149.047],
    [-35.227, -35.179, -35.295]
)
```

This appeared to work ...

[image]

... until I tried to write the GeoDataFrame to file:

```py
gdf.to_file("gdf.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")
```

This yielded the following error:

`ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'>`

Can I get GeoPandas to work with columns of lists, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoPandas uses `fiona` to handle most of the stuff within `read_file` and it seems that fiona is unable to handle list in this case.

But GeoPandas can also generate JSON by itself, and it seems that in that case, it works correctly.

Using that second gdf made from pandas:

```py
>>> print(gdf.to_json(indent=4))
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "district": "Belconnen",
                "values": [
                    0.62,
                    0.68,
                    0.74
                ]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    149.042,
                    -35.227
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "district": "Gungahlin",
                "values": [
                    0.55,
                    0.61,
                    0.67
                ]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    149.131,
                    -35.179
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "district": "Molonglo",
                "values": [
                    0.59,
                    0.66,
                    0.73
                ]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    149.047,
                    -35.295
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea. But when I save the file:
    <pre><code>
`import json` <br/>
`import geopandas as gpd` <br/>
</code>

with open(gnrlSruveyPrd+os.sep+keyc+'historical.json','w') as file:
   json.dump(gdf.to_json(),file)

Geopandas cannot read the json file

with open(gnrlSruveyPrd+os.sep+keyc+'historical.json','r')as jsf:
jsonfl=json.load(jsf)
#Then I tried to read the features but the json file is a string, not an object. I read it might be due to a ',' in the file.
gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(jsonfl)
(I gave up in trying to correctly format my comment)

Comment: Is there a way to force utf-8 instead of ascii as in vanilla pandas?

Comment: Yes, according to <https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/main/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L846> you can just pass `ensure_ascii=False`

Answer (score -1):

Your error code says you aren't saving a dataframe...

```
ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'list'>
```

It looks like you took the data out of the geoframe and combined to your list. If you like your second method, then save your other info...

```
| 0 | Belconnen | [0.62, 0.68, 0.74] 
| 1 | Gungahlin | [0.55, 0.61, 0.67]
| 2 | Molonglo | [0.59, 0.66, 0.73]
```

back into your geodataframe, then the geodataframe save to file should work, since you'll be saving a geoframe and not a list.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case. The command `type(gdf)` yields `geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame`, so it's clearly geodata. And the command `gdf.to_file("gdf.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")` calls the error.